# Can SUDS validate objects against XSD?

Tags: python, web-services, xsd, wsdl, suds

With Python I use SUDS for a Webservice client.

Before calling the webservice, the parameters will be built up in the code.

One of the parameters is defined to be a string between 4 and 8 characters for example.

Is it possible to validate such a parameter before it is sent?

Comment: I mean restrictions like http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp

Answer (score 0):

A quick peek at [the code](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/browser/trunk/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py) makes it look like only 'enumeration' restrictions are dealt with. SUDS shouldn't break on a length restriction, but wouldn't enforce it either.

The [`doctor`](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.xsd.doctor-module.html) module gives an interface for code that gets to inspect the schema (with the intention of fixing it up where it may be broken.) You might be able to use that to walk it looking for other restrictions you want to enforce and build a proxy of some sort to do so where needed. Alternatively it may be easier to just write some wrappers by hand if the number of places you need to deal with it is relatively small and static.